# vb.net JSON - Use Label Text In If Count

Tags: json, vb.net, if-statement, count

Snippet Taken From A Valid JSON

```
 "stats": [
{
  "stat": 32,
  "amount": 651,
  "reforgedAmount": -434
},
{
  "stat": 5,
  "amount": 2001
},
{
  "stat": 36,
  "amount": 1544
},
{
  "stat": 7,
  "amount": 3362
},
{
  "stat": 49,
  "amount": 434,
  "reforged": true
}
],
"armor": 2244
},
```

My Current Code To Make It Work

```
If jResults("items")("head")("stats").Count() > 1 Then
```

this will make it work but it is not ideal as i would have to produce new popup box for every item

But if i want to use label text instead i have tried it two ways and it fails the first is

```
If jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.text)("stats").Count() > 1 Then
```

This Causes A Exception To Be Thrown {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

i have also tried

```
Dim charitem As String
charitem = itemtypelbl.Text

If jResults("items")(charitem)("stats").Count() > 1 Then
```

this also causes the same exception any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to debug and look more closely at value of `itemtypelbl.text`. Make sure there is no unwanted characters/whitespace. You can check this way, for example :

```
itemtypelbl.text == "head"
```

It could caused by `itemtypelbl.text` contains unexpected value. In that case, you get nothing from `jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.text)` because `jResults("items")` doesn't have property with that name. And trying to get value from `Nothing` :

```
jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.text)("stats").Count()
```

will trigger such null reference exception.

Comment: i know that itemtypelbl.text already is head as i set it using the parent by doing `itempopup.itemtypelbl.Text = "head"` this is why i am confused :)